# Using AutoMapper to lookup related object and add it as a property

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework-6, automapper

I have an application running on `Entity Framework 6, Model First`, running on a legacy database.

In the application we have a `Person` object, who has one or more `Address`-objects. These are linked using an extra tabel: `PersonXAddress`, like this:

```
Person
    Id
    Name
    ...


PersonXAddress
    PersonId
    AddressId

Address
   Id
   Street
   PostalCode
   ...
```

Using `AutoMapper`, I have added a property to my PersonDto "HomeAddres", which is the Address with `AddressType == 1`, like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Person, PersonDto>()
   .ForMember(x => x.HomeAddress,
       o => o.MapFrom(y => y.PersonXAddresses
              .Where(a => a.Address.AddressTypeId == 1)
              .Select(x => x.Address).FirstOrDefault();
```

So in my code I'll never have to iterate through all the different Addresses to find that Person's HomeAddress.

But, I find this is very slow. It creates a HUGE sql query (about 50 lines of sql) and running this query for the first time can take up to 30 seconds. After firing it a first time, the query can take almost 1 second to just get some Person objects from the database. 
I've found that if I comment out the mapping above , the generated query fires up in less than a second and returns results in a few milliseconds.

Is there a better way of looking up the HomeAddress automagically? Can you offer me any help on what I can improve?

Thanks a lot

Comment: if you create foreign key deference you will have address available. you did not have write any extra line to code to get address .

Comment: A Foreign key from Person to Address is not possible because there may be multiple Addresses. The extra code is there to make sure that I don't have to iterate every PersonXAddress-object just to find the HomeAddress every time

Comment: you can use many to many relation that may help with a third class that contain primary keys of both database

Comment: How can an address be typed as "home address" if it possibly belongs to multiple persons? What if it belongs to someone else who has another home address? Maybe the "home address" flag should be in the junction record.

Comment: I also suspect that this is an indexing issue rather than a SQL generation issue. 50 Lines is really not that much considering that each column in a `SELECT` takes one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You look like you have a modeling problem. You should have a HomeAddress on your Person model (and database table). You're making an assumption in that LINQ query that there is zero or one home address. Just model that explicitly at the DB level.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it with just LINQ:

```
var personDTO = context.Person
               .Where(p => p.Id == 1)
               .Select(p => new {
                  person = p,
                  homeAddress = p.PersonXAddresses
                                 .FirstOrDefault(px => px.Address.AddressTypeID == 1)
                                 .Address })
               .Select(pd > new PersonDto {
                   Id = person.Id
                   Name = person.Name,
                   ...
                   HomeAddress = homeAddress
               }).ToList();
```

Also, make sure you have proper indices (AddressTypeID, etc).

Answer (score 0):

This is now solvable using the AutoMapper `ProjectTo<>` extensions found in the Automapper Queryable Extensions library.

Your query can now look like this (using the EF Plus `IncludeFilter` extension for convenience, and assuming your EF schema has abstracted away the cross-reference table):

```
context.Persons
       .IncludeFilter(p => p.Addresses.Where(a => a.AddressTypeId == 1))
       .ProjectTo<PersonDTO>();
```

Your map would look like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Person, PersonDTO>()
      .ForMember(x => x.HomeAddress,
                 o => o.MapFrom(y => y.Addresses.FirstOrDefault()));
```

The advantage of using the `ProjectTo<>` extension is that the query to the database itself will only include the fields required for the mapping, avoiding oversubscription issues.  As always, be sure to index your table joins for performance.